# парсинг джсон ответа ajax

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, long-polling

пытаюсь сделать лонг пулинг, но в жс выдает ошибку, при этом раньше была ошибка по выводу хтмл кода в джсон, сейчас просто uncaught
прилагаю код на жс, пхп, и несколько функций, которые использую на стороне сервака

```
<script>
                            function check(t){
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: 'im.php',
                                    method: 'POST',
                                    data: { "ts": t, "wait": 20, "group_id": <?php echo $wo['group_profile']['group_id'] ?> },
                                    success: function(data){
                                        try {
                                            var d = JSON.parse(data);
                                            localStorage.setItem("ts", d.ts);
                                            console.log(d);
                                            $('#helppp').html(d.content);
                                            setTimeout(check(d.ts), 1000);
                                        }catch(error) {
                                            alert('Error parsing JSON:', error.message);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            var t = localStorage.ts;
                            check(t);
                        </script>
```

im.php

```
<?php
// Последнее изменение файла
function getLastModified()
{
    $ts_file = Wo_All_Chat_Select_Last_Time($_POST['group_id']);
    return $ts_file;
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

    $ts = $_POST['ts'];
    $wait = $_POST['wait'];

    if ($ts === "undefined") {
        $data['ts'] = getLastModified();
        $data['content'] = Wo_All_Chat_SelectLast($_POST['group_id']);
        echo json_encode($data);
        return;
    }

    // Текущее время плюс ожидание
    $w = (time() + $wait);

    // Крутим бесконечный цикл
    while (true) {

        // Проверяем изменение файла
        if ($ts < getLastModified()) {
            // Сразу возвращаем ответ если было изменение
            $data['ts'] = getLastModified();
            $data['content'] = Wo_All_Chat_SelectLast($_POST['group_id']);
            echo json_encode($data);
            return;
        }

        // Отдаем ответ после максимального ожидания
        if (time() >= $w) {
            $data['ts'] = getLastModified();
            $data['content'] = Wo_All_Chat_SelectLast($_POST['group_id']);
            echo json_encode($data);
            return;
        }

        // Спим секунду
        sleep(1);
    }

}
```

фкнкция ласт тайм

```
function Wo_All_Chat_Select_Last_Time($group_id){
    global $wo, $sqlConnect;
    if ($wo['loggedin'] == false) {
        return false;
    }
    $query = mysqli_query($sqlConnect, "SELECT `date` FROM  `Chat_Group` WHERE `group_id` = {$group_id} ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1");
    $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    return $res;
}
```

функция ласт селект чат

```
function Wo_All_Chat_SelectLast($group_id){
    global $wo, $sqlConnect;
    if ($wo['loggedin'] == false) {
        return false;
    }
    $query = mysqli_query($sqlConnect, "SELECT `name`, `text` FROM  `Chat_Group` WHERE `group_id` = {$group_id} ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1");
    $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $name = $res['name'];
    $text = $res['text'];
    return "
    \"<li>\"
     \"<div class=\"group-chat-message\">\"
     \"<div class\"group-chat-message-container group-chat-my-message\">\"
     \"<span class=\"group-chat-message-username\">\"$name\"</span>\"
     \"<br>\"
     \"<span class=\"group-chat-message-content\">\"$text\"</span>\"
    \"</div>\"
     \"</div>\"
     \"</li>\"";

}
```

да, я пытался изменить ласт функцию и возвращать просто массив данных , но положительного результата не дало

Comment: ну так посмотрите, что там у вас в ответ то пришло в аякс? зы: в целом если отправить хэдер с json, то не надо делать parse на стороне jquery. setTimeout тоже не ясно какие цели преследует. Оно первый аргументом принимает колбэк. а вы в аргумент взываете функцию и undefined в качестве ее результата передаете.

Comment: У меня еще ощущение, что **im.php** ничего не возвращает, а цикл while так вообще выглядит подозрительно. Отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте полный текст ошибки, который возникает у вас.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была именно в файле с кодм пхп, итак, начну с начала, возможно, я тоже кому то помогу, решил посмотреть какой приходит джсон, и увидел фалс, в контенте, дальше полез в код функций пхп и понял, что у меня стоит проверка на логин, которая и ретернает фалс, но мои мучения на этом не остановились, джсон стабильно отказывался что то приходить, и тут я вспомнил, что нужно ещё подключить инит файл со всем, чем я пользуюсь, и о чудо, все заработало, при этом Лонг пуллинг работает пока без нареканий, но есть пару НО, долгая загрузка страницы, после отправки формы, возможно, это из-за сет таймаута, как только разберусь, сразу скину апдейт, а так, в общем, внимательности всем, и терпения, особенно таким Джунам как я